# Try/Catch is not suppressing ODBC driver error message

Tags: .net, vb.net, teradata

I'm attempting to handle login errors before advancing to the next form and, for the most part, everything is working.  I am having one problem - when the network connection is not established, the ODBC driver provides its own ugly error message.

Here's my code:

```
Try
     ODBCconnection.Open()
     ODBCconnection.Close()
     Me.Hide()
     otherForm.ShowDialog()
Catch ex As Exception
     If ex.Message.IndexOf("ugly network problem message") > -1 Then
         MsgBox("fancy network problem message")
     ElseIf ex.Message.IndexOf("other error message") > -1 Then
         MsgBox("fancy other error message")
     End If
End Try
```

So, if "other error message" is caught, it shows "fancy other error message", but if "ugly network problem message" is caught, it shows both the ugly and the fancy error messages.

My thought it that the driver itself is generating a message, any ideas on how to suppress it?

Comment: Could it be possible that the exception being thrown does not inherit from System.Exception, so it is not being catch?

Comment: @xfx If that were true, wouldn't it not display my error message also?

Comment: No. If the exception does not inherit from System.Exception, the Catch will do nothing. When you get the error, does Visual Studio stops and displays the line producing the error? If it does, click on the "View Detail" link and see if the dialog provides any information as to the base-type of the exception.

Comment: @xfx No, there is no error in the debugger, just a msgbox from the driver and then my msgbox.

Comment: Try `Catch ex As ODBCException` instead.

Comment: @Ciarán I get the same behavior.

Comment: Is it possible that you update the ODBC drivers?
Or, perhaps you should try to contact Teradata's support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to handle that specific ODBC exception before handling the `System.Exception` exception.

To Answer your question about the specifics...

```
Try
     ODBCconnection.Open()
     ODBCconnection.Close()
     Me.Hide()
     otherForm.ShowDialog()
Catch oex as System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException
     'Do something with the OdbcException
Catch ex As Exception
     If ex.Message.IndexOf("ugly network problem message") > -1 Then
         MsgBox("fancy network problem message")
     ElseIf ex.Message.IndexOf("other error message") > -1 Then
         MsgBox("fancy other error message")
     End If
End Try
```

The rule is that your exception handling must flow from more to less specific or from derived Exception classes to their base classes all the way back to `System.Exception`. In other words, if you have any specific exceptions to handle you must handle those before you handle the `System.Exception` exception...

In Visual Studio exception helper that pops up when you place a break point in your `Catch ex As Exception` block you can see exactly what is the exception that is being thrown and that is the exception that you must catch before your `Catch ex As Exception` block...

[image: Exception Helper]

As you can see from the screenshot the VS exception helper displays the exact name of the Exception and if you click on 'View Detail' you get a window with many more details including the full namespace of the exception that occurred... have you ever seen this Exception Helper or are you using some other IDE?

Comment: And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Ciaran suggested that and it didn't have any effect.  OdbcException inherits from System.Exception, so Exception will (and does) catch it, but that's after the driver has displayed its own error message:

    ---------------------------
    Teradata TDATA.DLL
    ---------------------------
     10065 WSA E HostUnreach: The Teradata server can't currently be     reached over this network

Comment: Than you need to catch that exception first... In Visual Studio exception helper that pops up when you place a break point in your Catch ex As Exception block you can see exactly what is the exception that is being thrown and that is the exception that you must catch before your Catch ex As Exception block...

Comment: Okay then I guess a better question is - how do I find what type of exception is thrown by that error message?

Comment: Hmm... it states that it's an OdbcException.  This situation won't happen often enough to actually matter if I just allow the ugly error message to appear, so I'll just do that.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that.  I'm using VS2010.  I've determined that the driver, for this exception only, creates its own alert box before it actually throws the exception.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like they have several discussions about this error over on teradata.com... 
http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/10065-wsa-e-hostunreach
Perhaps you'll find a solution there...